# Kendo UI Grid Using In-Cell and Inline

Tags: grid, kendo-ui, edit

I have searched endlessly for the answer of this and have a feeling this is not supported. But I want to double check before I give up.

I have a Kendo Grid where I want incell editing turned on if a column downs not have a value and want inline editing for the rows that this column does have a value.

If this is possible, how do I go about implementing this.

Here is what I've tired,
Tried grid default to inline, but never got the cell edit to work. 
Tried grid to default to in-cell, where on the edit event, I check to see for this column to see if there is a value, if there is, I close the cell. I added a custom commands button, and tried enable edit mode on the row from the click event. But it seems that you can't do this.

Here is what my click event did...

```
editClick = function(e) {
    var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
    var row = grid.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
    grid.editRow(row); 
};
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is **not** supported - the Grid cannot switch between the different editing modes on the fly and work-around is kinda impossible.